# How to create proper iOS CoreData database model?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, model

I have been learning CoreData to use it in my application and have some problems generating sql model.

I would like to have two entities (at least). One is `Items`, other is `History`.
Logic: every history entity should have none or many `Items`. `Items` shouldn't duplicate each other - uniques.

How can I model this in Xcode? Do I need a linking entity like "History2Items"?

I have been struggling this for a while but I can figure it out the proper solution.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

I have made this model:

[image: CoreData model]

For fetching data I used relationship for prefetching:

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"item"]];
```

And that's how I get Items for each History:

> ```
> History *history = [self.historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
> NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[history.item allObjects]];
> ```

Just looped over items array to get each Item.

It's that easy. Thanks to @Ashley Mills.

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't have any Xcode around at the moment. But as far as I know, you can just create both entities in the graphical editor and connect them and set the appropriate relationship (1:n, n:1, 1:1 etc.)

Comment: That's what I did but does not work. I need some kind of a "linking" entity. Look my response bellow Answer 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Item` and `History` entities and connect them as follows:

[image]

If an `Item` can belong to more than one `History`, change the relationship from one-to-many to a many-to-many.

You only need a linking entity if you intend on ordering the items for a history by an index, as each item could have a different index for a given history. If you're ordering items by date for example, no linking entity would be required.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Item entity should have unique items. That means two History elements can have the same Item. In SQL world I would create a linking entity. Am I correct?

Comment: This isn't SQL, so try to forget what you know from there! Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I have done this. For now it looks good. But I have another problem. I want to get items for selected history. For now I've made this: History *history = [self.historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; NSMutableArray *items = [history.item allObjects]; But every item object has data: <fault>. How is that?

Comment: A fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that has not yet been fully realised. The fault will be resolved when you access the data.

Comment: That's correct. But I want to know the last part - how can I access data for specific History object? I just tried to do NSFetchRequest to pull all Items for selected History object with no luck. Still getting <fault>.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you've written so far